# Monit SSL/TLS version not updating for port 2812?

Tags: monit

Currently running monit 5.16 on a CentOS7 host. I am trying to stop the use of TLSv1 and TLSv12. I have tried every iteration of the set httpd port 2812 config on /etc/monitrc but nothing is working.

Right now my monitrc has:
set SSL options {
VERIFY: ENABLE
CLIENTPEMFILE: 
CACERTIFCATEFILE: <dir to .crt>
}

set httpd port 2812
SSL ENABLE
PEMFILE 
allow usr:pass

This works but TLSv1 and TLSv11 is still capable when I run our scanner. When I try to add:

set httpd port 2812
SSL ENABLE
with ssl {
pemfile: 
version: TLSv12
}
allow usr:pass

I get a syntax error "{" and an error that there is no pemfile. Essentially everytime I add the "with ssl {" it get the syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Your sample does not fit to monit 5.16, the syntax is used since monit 5.21.

Syntax for TCP port used by monit 5.16.

```
  SET HTTPD PORT <number> [ADDRESS <hostname | IP-address>]
      [SSL <ENABLE | DISABLE>]
      [PEMFILE <path>]
      [CLIENTPEMFILE <path>]
      [ALLOWSELFCERTIFICATION]
      [SIGNATURE <ENABLE | DISABLE>]
      ALLOW <user:password | IP-address | IP-range>+
```

And for the ssl option the following was used by monit 5.16.

```
  SET <SSL | TLS> [OPTIONS] {
      VERSION: <AUTO | SSLV2 | SSLV3 | TLSV1 | TLSV11 | TLSV12>
      VERIFY: <ENABLE | DISABLE>
      SELFSIGNED: <ALLOW | REJECT>
      CLIENTPEMFILE: <path>
      CACERTIFICATEFILE: <path>
      CACERTIFICATEPATH: <path>
}
```

A suggestion, use a newer monit version, if available or at least monit 5.19 with old systems.